# What am I doing wrong with my GridBagLayout placement?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I know there are many GridBagLayout questions here, but I couldn't seem to find anyone with quite the same problem that I am having. I am attempting to organize some buttons and panels using GridBagLayout in a 6x3 grid, such that elements can split any row in half or in thirds (using widths of 3 and 2). Is seems that rows are effectively only being divided in half however, does anyone know why the elements don't appear to be accurately following the placement instructions? I believe the provided code should be all that is relevant. I apologize in advance for any missing information or broken conventions, this is my first time asking a question here. Thanks!

[Area organized by GridBagLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTFC.png)

```
// making generation panel
JPanel generationPanel = new JPanel();
generationPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
generationPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("new world generation"));
generationPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
generationPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
controlPanel.add(generationPanel);

// adding generate button
JButton resetButton = new JButton("Generate");
resetButton.setActionCommand("reset");
resetButton.addActionListener(this);
generationPanel.add(resetButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0.45,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));

// adding width and height inputs
widthInput = new JTextArea("" + width);
widthInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));
JPanel widthHolder = new JPanel();
widthHolder.add(widthInput);
widthHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("width"));
generationPanel.add(widthHolder, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0.45,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));

heightInput = new JTextArea("" + height);
heightInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));
JPanel heightHolder = new JPanel();
heightHolder.add(heightInput);
heightHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("height"));
generationPanel.add(heightHolder, new GridBagConstraints(4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0.45,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));

// adding world type dropdown
worldType = new JComboBox<>(new String[]
        {"mountain island", "flat land", "continent", "archipelago", "last custom"});
worldType.setSelectedIndex(0);
//worldType.setActionCommand("reset");
//worldType.addActionListener(this);
generationPanel.add(new JLabel("world type:"), new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 2, 1,
    0.333, 0.20, 10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
generationPanel.add(worldType, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 4, 1, 0.666, 0.25,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));

// adding new window buttons
JButton openSelection = new JButton("Open Selection");
openSelection.setActionCommand("openSelection");
openSelection.addActionListener(this);
generationPanel.add(openSelection, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 3, 1, 0.5, 0.30,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));

JButton newWindow = new JButton("New Window");
newWindow.setActionCommand("newWindow");
newWindow.addActionListener(this);
generationPanel.add(newWindow, new GridBagConstraints(3, 2, 3, 1, 0.5, 0.30,
    10, 1, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
```

Comment: It’s difficult to tell what you want, but I suspect you are expecting GridBagLayout to divide your generationPanel evenly into thirds.  GridBagLayout does not work like that—its cells are flexible.  If a column has no components in it, its preferred width is zero.  If you want grid cells which are all exactly the same size, use [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) instead of GridBagLayout.